# Is there a way to remove the history for a single file in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I think I already know the answer to this but thought I would ask anyway:

We have a file that got added to a Mercurial repository with sensitive information in it. Is there any way to remove that file along with its change history without removing the whole repo?

Comment: this answer helped me, even though it's not "removing" but converting the repo to itself (and you lose all the changesets IDs) :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22607889/714733

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you can't. Read the *[changes that should have never been](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html#sec:undo:aaaiiieee)* section of the mercurial red book about it; and particularly the *[what about sensitive changes that escape](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html#id394667)* subsection, which contains this paragraph:

> Mercurial also does not provide a way
>   to make a file or changeset completely
>   disappear from history, because there
>   is no way to enforce its
>   disappearance; someone could easily
>   modify their copy of Mercurial to
>   ignore such directives. In addition,
>   even if Mercurial provided such a
>   capability, someone who simply hadn't
>   pulled a “make this file disappear”
>   changeset wouldn't be affected by it,
>   nor would web crawlers visiting at the
>   wrong time, disk backups, or other
>   mechanisms. Indeed, no distributed
>   revision control system can make data
>   reliably vanish. Providing the
>   illusion of such control could easily
>   give a false sense of security, and be
>   worse than not providing it at all.

The usual way to revert committed changes is supported by mercurial through the `backout` command (again, mercurial book: [*dealing with committed changes*](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html#id392218)) but the information does not disappear from the repository: since you never know who exactly cloned your repository, that would give a false sense of security, as explained above.

Comment: Yes you can: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/232-removing-files-from-mercurial-history/ Of course all of you must reclone your repos, but you don't loose whole history.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, it is not the correct answer. @wrzasa referenced the correct answer in his comment. I have personally done what the OP asked multiple times using info from that link.

Answer (score 62):

It is correct that you cannot easily remove a particular file from Mercurial in the sense that doing so will disrupt all the changeset IDs in your repository. When you change the changeset IDs, everybody has to re-clone the repository. See the [Wiki page about editing history](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/EditingHistory) for information about the consequences of modifying the history in Mercurial.

If that is okay to you (internal repository in a company), then take a look at the [convert extension](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ConvertExtension). It can do **hg → hg** conversions and has a **--filemap** argument which can be used to **exclude** files, among other things.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103227/how-do-you-remove-big-files-from-history-in-mercurial for dealing with an issue in a certain Mercurial version.

Comment: Thanks Martin, rescued a massively bloated repository full of compiled binary objects. Saved the day!

Answer (score 9):

It can be done in under 10 min. in a single repository, although there are consequences.

How: use hg convert as described in [this excellent guide](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/232-removing-files-from-mercurial-history/). Basically, you "convert" an Hg repo into a new Hg repo, but you get to specify a list of files to exclude during conversion. This is an excerpt of the key steps:

```
Make sure all your teammates have pushed their local changes to the central repo (if any)
Backup your repository
Create a "map.txt" file:

# this filemap is used to exclude specific files
exclude "subdir/filename1.ext"
exclude "subdir/filename2.ext"
exclude "subdir2"

Run this command:
hg convert --filemap map.txt c:/oldrepo c:/newrepo
NOTE: You have to use "forward-slash" in paths, even on windows.
Wait and be patient
Now you have a new repo at c:\newrepo but without the files
```

As for the consequences...

- all changeset IDs after the files you want to exclude were added will be different
- the new "clean" main repository will have to be manually put in place of the existing one
- all team members will have to make new clones of the main repo
- any other services which integrate with Hg may require attention (e.g. the issue tracker, a code review system etc.)

Comment: This worked for me without issues. Note that the exclude filenames are case sensitive even on windows.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible locally, but not globally, and it changes the ID of each commit after the point at which the file was added.  In order for the change to stick, you'll need access to every single copy of the repository, particularly the ones that get pulled or pushed from.

That said, I have followed the [Editing History](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory) sequence described on the Mercurial wiki to remove a file from one of my repositories.  This sequence assumes that revision 1301:5200a5a10d8b added the file `path/to/badfile.cfg`, which was not changed in any subsequent revision:

1. Enable the MQ extension in your `.hgrc`:

   ```
   [extensions]
   mq =
   ```
2. Pull recent changes from upstream.

   ```
   hg pull
   ```
3. Import everything from the file addition onward into MQ:

   ```
   hg qimport -r 1301:tip
   hg qpop -a
   ```
4. Remove the file from the commit that added it.

   ```
   hg qpush 1301.diff
   hg forget path/to/badfile.cfg
   hg qrefresh
   ```
5. Convert the patches into new Mercurial revisions.

   ```
   hg qpush -a
   hg qfinish -a
   ```
6. Push the new revisions upstream.

   ```
   hg push -f
   ```
7. **On the upstream repository** and every single other copy, remove the old revisions.

   ```
   hg strip 5200a5a10d8b
   ```

**Warning**: This step may destroy work, unless you're careful.  If anybody has committed anything since the last time you pulled from upstream, then you'll have to rebase that work before stripping.  Unfortunately, the `rebase` extension is not helpful here; you'll have to use MQ again, converting the new commits into patches that you apply onto the new tip.

Good luck.

Comment: I had to `hg phase --secret --force 1301` before this worked like a charm.

Comment: Interesting.  It looks like phases are a bit different, though, hiding the whole commit instead of removing a file from the commit.  They also probably won't remove or hide the commit for the upstream repository.

Answer (score -2):

hg transplant, then hg strip

Comment: The file goes through almost the entire change history. Can you expand on how you could use the commands above to purge the file history from the repo while leaving the change history for the other files intact?

Comment: You cannot use transplant to remove a single file from a changeset -- transplant only know how to move whole changesets from one branch or repository to another (it's like hg export | hg import). See my answer about the convert extension.