# Wiping a sensitive file from a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to completely remove a file and all traces of it from a mercurial repository? There was a commit of a file with some sensitive information and would like to know if it's possible to wipe all traces of it from the repository.

[Seems it is possible with Git.](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to remove the history for a single file in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029480/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-history-for-a-single-file-in-mercurial)

Comment: @Wooble, Yes seems a duplicate, will close it. Couldn't find through search.

Comment: I will not delete the questions though so that it shows up in search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, by using the [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension), using the --filemap option and exclude the file.

But I think (as you mess with the relations between the changeset IDs and change the changeset DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) you end up with a new repository which cannot push/pull with the old one. Hope that's not a problem for you.

Run some tests on it :D

Comment: I think this is the only viable solution as well, after having done some more research.