# Mercurial - largefiles & bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I just got the latest mercurial and started adding in largefiles.

However, now I can't push changes:

```
abort: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/mysite/bitbucket.org does not appear to be a largefile store
```

How can I push to bitbucket now?  I have multiple commits that include *both* largefiles and regular code commits.  I'm OK with just `forget`ing all the largefiles I've added, but how can I do that without reverting all of my real commits?

Comment: Have you followed the [wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension)?

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately, it looks like largefiles is not enabled on bitbucket.  http://groups.google.com/group/bitbucket-users/browse_thread/thread/58e54f1a9cf1a705.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029480/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-history-for-a-single-file-in-mercurial), you can use the [convert extension](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ConvertExtension) to create a new repository.  Use `--filemap` to exclude the large files you don't want.  This might be a problem if you have already pushed (other files) to bitbucket.  Luckily, there is another answer to the same question which discusses [editing history](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory) and has a recipe to remove a file from history.  Since I'm assuming that you haven't pushed the large file anywhere you should be okay.

Comment: Well, that's certainly the solution I was looking for.  Unfortunately, I get this error: `abort: No such file or directory: /my/large/file` during the conversion step for the commit in which I had added the large files.  Is this a bug in one of the mercurial extensions?

Comment: Sounds like there is a bug with how the convert and large file extensions interact.  Perhaps the editing history recipe will work.