# How do you remove big files from history in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I have just created a mercurial repo created from a heterogeneous ecosystems of other repos. Before I publish it to my co-workers, I want to clean it as much as possible. To this end, I'd like to entirely remove a few big old files from history (pretend they never existed), so repo will be smaller.

Is this possible with mercurial?

Comment: Don't understand the "off-topic" close vote; this question is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Graham, are you saying you think software engineers should use revision control?  That's crazy talk...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check out the `convert` extension, particularly the `--filemap` option.

Enable by adding the following to `mercurial.ini`:

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

Create a map of files to exclude:

```
exclude path/to/file1
exclude path/to/file2
```

Then convert the repo:

```
hg convert srcrepo destrepo --filemap <map>
```

Note there is a bug in Mercurial 2.1.1 causing an error with the above command:

```
initializing destination destrepo repository
abort: invalid mode ('r') or filename
```

Just add the `--splicemap <nonexistent file>` option to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The documentation for --filemap is pretty scarce, would you have a link explaining it with a little more detail?

Comment: I have just tested your method. The files are removed from the working directory, but they still seem to be in .hg/store/data. Do you know how to remove them from there as well?

Comment: @static_rtti, did you look in the destination repo?  The files are completely gone in my test.

Comment: OK, I've found out what was going on: some files had been moved around, and I had to put the original file path in the file map as well as the new path.

Comment: As I've thought through what Mercurial supports, it looks to me like the only way to remove *every* binary file from the repository's history is to go through the effort of finding every binary and its renames and adding each one manually to the map. Is that accurate?

Comment: @ChrisKrycho, it could be automated.  `hg locate set:binary` will find any binary in the working folder.  `hg log -r "file('set:binary() and copied()')"` can find any revision with a binary file present and a copy was made.  A little scripting and it wouldn't be painful.

Comment: Ooh, that could be extremely handy. Looks like I'm going to be doing some reading on `hg locate`. Thanks much for the info.

Comment: Great tip. I was able to remove personal data from a long ago committed file. BTW: my filemap file had an extra linefeed at the end, which may have caused the first try to not remove the file. I haven't tested that theory though. Thanks!

Comment: Minor note: you can load the convert extension without editing hgrc.  If this is a one-off thing (it was for me), I'd rather do it that way.  `hg --config=extensions.convert= convert --filemap map.txt old new`.