# How to use hg convert properly

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

at one point I committed large files to my hg repository, I later did a `hg forget` on these files, but now my repository is quite big and on every new clone it takes ages as these files are still being pulled down as part of the history.

I am using this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103227/how-do-you-remove-big-files-from-history-in-mercurial) to try and `convert` my repository into a repository that doesn't know of the large files. I am doing the following

assume my repository has the following structure:

```
~/workspace/
    project/
        data/
            large_file.txt
        src/
            ...
```

I am doing the following

```
cd workspace/project
echo data/large_file.txt >> /tmp/myfilemap
hg convert --filemap ~/workspace/project ~/workspace/new_repo
```

However the `new_repo` just appears to be empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The convert action operates within the working directory so you probably don't want to start the operation from in there.

The command format is as follows:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap_path SourceRepoPath TargetRepoPath
```

You can use relative paths, but put the filemap outside the repos.

Your filemap contents should be formatted like so:

```
exclude "data/large_file.txt"
```

Comment: After this is done, do I just push the new repo up and will it replace the history of the old. Or is this a completely new repository and I have to delete the old one and just use this one?

Comment: Just tried this but still the same result targetRepoPath is created but is empty...

Comment: Are you seeing any output at the command line at all? If it's running remotely correctly you should see messages about "initializing the destination" and then it should list out all the revisions as they're processed. Have you tried using explicit paths to everything and leaving out the filemap for a first attempt?

Comment: @Aly facing the same kinda problem. The repository is empty after running hg convert. May I know how u fixed this one?